# Deployment methodology for many Azure App Services

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, azure-webjobs

We currently use a very traditional deployment methodology. Developers build EXE packages which are then handed to the operations team who install it onto VMs (one VM per customer). Our company is B2B and resources between customers is rarely shared.

Now, we are looking at using Azure App Services to deploy software.

I can deploy our app to Azure App Services, but what is the recommended way to deploy to many customers? The documentation online talks a lot about continuous deployment, so is the expectation that we maintain deployment profiles for each customer?

Comment: This is very broad question, can you share a little more context on your development, build and deployment environment?

Comment: At the moment we are developing on local machines and deploy to a test Azure App Service, this is where non-customer testing is performed by QA internal to the company. There is an expectation that our customers do not want to share App Services with other customers, so I am wondering what is the recommended way of doing that, are we meant to maintain deployment profiles for each customer, or clone the app service somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I would start with exploring the AZ-CLI to script creation of AppServices. Then use the AZ-CLI to deploy your apps to the different customer app services. With regards to the different customers: I would start with an AppService per customer within a single App Service Plan, in that way you can limit the costs for now.

We use Azure DevOps build and release pipelines for creating (and updating) App Services and also for building and deploying to these app services. Based on certain conditions we first deploy to Development, after approval gates to Test, QA and finally Production. Nowadays we use YAML pipelines for most tasks, but we started with Azure Portal and AZ-CLI. It takes time to evolve from manual deployment to fully automated.

Comment: Did you package your software in some way to be deployed with AZ-CLI scripts, or were the scripts publishing from source?

Comment: Depends on the specific framework that we use. For Angular we use a specific build step and then upload the dist folder to the  app service. For Python (FastAPI) we let the app service do an install step. We started doing this from our local development environment. Now we use the piplines to build artefacts (zip files with the content that we want to put on the app service) and those are then deployed on the app services. All of the settings are stored in Web App Configuration settings, so we can build once and deploy to all different environments without having to rebuild).